# Error while concatenating query for SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, string

I am getting aerror while concatenating query for SQL in PHP

```
$query = "INSERT INTO bookings (date, start, userId)
VALUES ('$booking_date','$booking_time','$_SESSION['userIdSession']');";
```

The single quotes `''` in `$_SESSION['userIdSession']`        are causing this problem.

What is the right way to concatenate this string without getting error?

(I am beginner in PHP, do not down vote me)

Comment: Try to use *Prepared Statements* instead.

Comment: See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: oops, my bad, add a variable, `$userIdSession = $_SESSION['userIdSession']`

Comment: @user3052629 That doesn't make it *safe*.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely what you are looking for:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO bookings (date, start, userId)
VALUES ('" . $booking_date . "','" . $booking_time . "','" . $_SESSION['userIdSession'] . "');";
```

However always make sure you are protecting against SQL Injections, else you might end up with serious problems if someone manage to mess with your database through unprotected user input.

Comment: What's wrong with curly braces?

Comment: First of all SO removed them automaticly, besides it is better without and then have that formating as I just posted. The bad thing when using them is to make sure the server and mysql is supporting and allowing the use of them.

Answer (score -1):

When using array variables in double-quoted strings, you must surround them with curly brackets:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO bookings (date, start, userId)
    VALUES ('$booking_date','$booking_time','{$_SESSION['userIdSession']}');";
```

Otherwise PHP will not correctly recognize the array access in the string.

Additionally, you must prevent SQL Injection as stated in the comments above.